# Create a 3D polygon

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, polygons

We can look at the dimension of a shape using `RegionDimension`, for example

```
RegionDimension /@ {Cuboid[], Cone[], Ball[]}
```

returns `{3,3,3}`. This is a 3D shape, i.e. it contains a volume (rather than say `Sphere[]`). This is very helpful when using `RegionMember[]`.

But, now I want to create my very own shape. But all my `Polygons` have a `RegionDimension` of 2. , e.g.

```
shape = Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}];
RegionDimension[shape]
```

Gives a result of `2`. How can I create a custom 3D polygon that acts in the same way as `Cuboid[]` - can I make a combination of `Cuboids[]` & `Cones[]` in one shape?

---

Edit to clarify question further I wish to be able to create custom shapes in Mathematica that have the same properties as `Cuboid[]`. What I am hoping for is `RegionMember` to give the general expression for the requirement to be within the shape. E.g

```
shape0 = Cuboid[];
shape1 = ConvexHullMesh[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}];
shape2 = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {50, 3}]];
shape3 = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 2}}, {Tetrahedron[{1, 2, 3, 5}], Tetrahedron[{1, 3, 4, 5}]}];
shape4 = BoundingRegion[{{7, 6, 2}, {7, 10, 2}, {9, 2, 6}, {2, 9, 3}, {5, 4, 5}}, "MinConvexPolyhedron"];
shape5 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Prism[{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}}]];


RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ {shape0, shape1, shape2, shape3, 
  shape4, shape5}
```

Note how `shape0` gives an expression, whereas the others remain in the shape form.

[image]

Comment: Try `Tetrahedron` instead of `Triangle`

Comment: `RegionMember` _does_ evaluate on these shape when the second argument is numeric. I would say that the behavior of `RegionMember` on `Cuboid[]` is rather nonstandard.

Answer (score 1):

A 3-point polygon in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defines a triangle, whose `RegionDimension` is 2. Mathematica is correct, and it's unclear what "hasn't been filled" means.

However, if you add a 4th point, you can generate a convex hull (one of many ways of defining 3d meshes):

```
shape = ConvexHullMesh[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
  Boxed -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
RegionDimension@shape
```

[image]

Comment: It would be even simpler with `Tetrahedron`. Apart from that: good explanation.

Comment: This method gives a different behaviour using `RegionMember` than `Cuboid[]`. Why might this be? e.g `RegionMember[shape, {x, y, z}]
RegionMember[Cuboid[], {x, y, z}] `.  (it works fine for values for x,y &z). Why might that be? This doesn't seem a fit in replacement for `Cuboid[]` to be able to make custom shapes.